# I am trying to write a program that will open a website at a particular time and click the options.(I am a beginner)

Tags: python

I have imported pyautogui- to move the mouse, schedule- to schedule when the actions have to take place, webbrowser- to open the web broweser and the website and time for `time.sleep`

```
import pyautogui 
import schedule
import webbrowser
import time

def auto():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/calendarv2')

def cl1():
    pyautogui.click(432, 559)
    pyautogui.click(589, 603)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(767, 635)

def cl2():
    pyautogui.click(444, 652)
    pyautogui.click(772, 552)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(767, 635)

def cl3():
    pyautogui.click(743, 329)
    pyautogui.click(824, 265)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(767, 635)

def cl4():
    pyautogui.click(491, 399)
    pyautogui.click(492, 552)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(767, 635)

schedule.every().week.at('08:27:00').do(auto, cl1)
schedule.every().week.at('09:27:00').do(cl2)
schedule.every().week.at('10:27:00').do(cl3)
schedule.every().week.at('11:27:00').do(cl4)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You have to specify your question in details. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I recommend to you to use https://www.selenium.dev for this kind of stuff

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title